# svn delete folder (OS Level)

Tags: svn

I am a newbie to SVN and somehow managed to import few projects to the repository created. I have somehow imported a project that wasn't required , hence would like to delete it.Going through information available online about svn delete , seems like does not completely remove it (OS Level) and traces would still remain.A delete too with rm -rf can be done only at the repository level.

Would be great to have inputs from experts here on any alternatives.My configurations are as below :

- Running svnserve -d on a FreeBSD box
- I have complete control over the repository (root access ! Yes managed to get that!!)

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to completely remove a file or a folder in svn repository is to manually dump the repository to a file, filter the dump and recreate the repository using that filtered dump file. This is really not stuff to be done by a newbie.

Why do you think you can't live with the history? I would really suggest that you do.

Comment: If he has control over this *fresh* repository, there's absolutely no need to keep unwanted contents in it. Why would you suggest that?

Comment: Where does he mention fresh? How fresh is fresh? If totally fresh then sure, why not play with the dumping and filtering or even start from scratch; delete the repo and create a new one. Anyhow I answered the question; dumping+filtering is the way to go if and _if_ you really need to do it.

Comment: @teroi : Thanks for your response.I am beginning to set up the repository and this is version 1 of the project ,hence wanted to keep it clean :) . If there is no way out I will have to stick to your input.Thanks again.

Comment: @Deepak Vn: No problem, as said if you are just starting to set up the repo, then the easiest way is to just delete the repo and create a new one. As an svn user you can't really poke the history but if you want to learn about the admin tools, google for svn repository dumping and filtering.